# expo cli is not loading my project and event not creating the new one

Tags: react-native, expo

my expo CLI is not loaded my existing app or even not created new app by using this command 'expo init testapp'. there are following screenshots of my problem.

[image]

it is not loading my existing app.

[image]

it is not going to create my new project.

Comment: `test` might be a reserved CLI keyword. Try `expo init my-first-app` or something like this

Answer (score 0):

error raise because of you didn't enter visible name of the project please add the name of the Application and you are able to create new application:

Expo CLI steps for android and IOS applications:
https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/expo-cli/

Steps:

1. expo init FirstApp
2. After that you have the options to select templates
3. After that you have the options to select workflow
4. After that you have to type your Application name which name is visible to you and others.

That's it your Application created check into directory.